# Match float number at the beginning of a text -Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match these examples flowing a format as #.###,##

Valid examples

```
455,80SomeText
1,00
30,82
7,78 SomeText
622,21
8.542,85
```

Invalid examples

```
455,482
54,1
7454,50
```

I have tried this: `^[0-9]+(\,[0-9][0-9])`

**Update 1**

- Number format #.###,##
- Could contain some text after the number

Comment: I don't understand why `1,00` is valid, and `54,1` is invalid?

Comment: In that case, should be 54,10
This is because I receive a text in that format.

Comment: What about `7454,50`?

Comment: In that case 7454,50 should be 7.454,50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't accounting for the thousands separator at all in your regex...

```
^[0-9]{0,3}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]{2}(?![0-9])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/oD2mJ8)

If you don't want to accept `,42` either, use:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]{2}(?![0-9])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zX7hL3)

`(?:\.[0-9]{3})*` allows for the thousands.

The comma doesn't need to be escaped, and `(?![0-9])` (a negative lookahead) is to prevent the number from being followed by more numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
^\-?\d{1,3}(\.\d\d\d)*(,\d+)?
```

Broken out:

```
^           # drop anchor at the start of the line. Then...
\-?         # match an optional negative sign, followed by...
\d{1,3}     # match 1-3 decimal digits, followed by...
(           # a group, consisting of
  \.        # * a thousands separator, followed by
  \d\d\d    # * 3 decimal digits 
)*          # with the group repeated zero or more times, followed by...
(           # a group, consisting of
  ,         # * a decimal point, followed by
  \d+       # * 1 or more decimal digits
)?          # with the group being optional
```

You should note that the thousands separator and decimal point are culture-specific. Further, not all cultures clump digits in groups of 3.

To make this portable across cultures, you'll need to instantiate a suitable [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx), drill down to its [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) property and build the regular expression on the fly using the culture's rules for how numbers are composed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what format you are looking for, but it sounds like you could use the repeat qualifiers in RegEx like `^[0-9]+(,[0-9]{2})`  I think the problem in your expression is you are escaping the comma which is not a regex special character.

Here is a good reference on RegEx: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html